# Accessing images from JAR library in Android

Tags: java, android, jar

I have compiled a JAR library for Android which contains some code and resources. (see below)
I would like to access the images in the library from my code.

What should I do to make the library resources accessible using eg. `R.drawable.album_artwork`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. You need to include the library as `library project`.
With the new build system gradle / android studio, you can move to .aar files which basically includes the library project in binary form.

For more information on how to create a library project, check out the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on "You need to include the library as library project."? I am using Eclipse.

Comment: added a link to the answer

Comment: So JAR libraries cannot contain images at all?

Comment: right. you really need to use a library project or a .aar file.

Comment: If I create library project, will it be linked to a specific IDE?

Comment: No, you can do it on the command line to. You may need to import it into your IDE. But this depends on the IDE. android-studio imports it automatically. You have to do it manually in eclipse. Just read the documentation I linked above.